# What is the equivalent of hook_translated_menu_link_alter() to alter a menu link?

Tags: 8, navigation

I want to alter the menu link in Drupal 8. In Drupal 7 we can achieve this using [`hook_translated_menu_link_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_translated_menu_link_alter/7.x).

```
function module_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map) {
  global $user;

  if (!empty($item['access'])) {
    // Administrator will access all menu's.
    if (strpos(current_path(), 'admin/structure/menu/manage/' . $item['menu_name']) === 0 && user_access('administer menu')) {
      return;
    }
    // If userid is equal to menu user id.
    if ($user->uid == 1) {
      $access = 'UNBLOCK';
      break;
    }
   // Block menu.
    else {
      $access = 'BLOCK';
    }
    // Access FALSE if Menu not for USER.
    if ($access == 'BLOCK') {
      $item['access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

In Drupal 7 I am hiding/disabling menu based on some conditions like the user ID.

Similarly, I want to alter the menu link in Drupal 8. How can I achieve it?

Comment: On this [page](https://beautiful7mind.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/whats-new-in-drupal-8-and-how-you-can-contribute/) if you scroll to end before comments, it has stated `hook_translated_menu_link_alter() has been replaced by hook_menu_link_load()`, I do not know whether it is right or wrong, I just found this. Might be you can make out. If, let me also know.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204582/alter-the-access-of-menu-link-before-rendering

Answer (score 4):

[HOOK_link_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.6.x) would be one D8 equivalent to hook_translated_menu_link_alter:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_link_alter().
 *
 * @inheritdoc
 */
function HOOK_link_alter(&$variables) {
  $url = $variables['url'];
  // Check url is routed in Drupal.
  if ($url->isRouted()) {
    // Load the current user by user ID.
    $currentUser = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    // Check access.
    $urlAccess = $url->access();
    // Get url options.
    $urlOptions = $url->getOptions();
    // Your code here.
  }
}
```

See Drupal 8 [class URL](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x) for more API info.

However, you could use [Hook_preprocess_HOOK()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) as such:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_hook().
 *
 * @inheritdoc
 */
function HOOK_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['menu_name']) && $variables['menu_name'] === 'menu_name') {
    foreach($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
      $url = $item['url']->toString();
      if ($url == '/user') {
        // Remove menu item.
        unset($variables['items'][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just checking `path` above, but it shows you can hide a single menu item based on certain criteria.

---

For the access restrictions, depending on your needs, you might look at routing and permissions based on the `entity` instead of the menu item and let Drupal handle the menu item display.

For menu access by role look at this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_role_access

Comment: `hook_link_alter()` is not thought as replacement of `hook_translated_menu_link_alter()` since there are only few keys that can be altered, and the *access* key is not one of those.

Answer (score 0):

From drupal.org on /node/2122241:

> Altering menu links and adding menu links dynamically
>
> Statically defined menu items may be altered using
>   hook_menu_links_discovered_alter() (but note there is no
>   hook_menu_link_discovered(), the menu links are built from the .yml
>   files as explained above). This hook may also be used to add new
>   dynamic menu items.
>
> More often, you may want to use a deriver class to add new menu link
>   plugins. For example Views provided menu links are added in
>   views.links.menu.yml, which specifies the deriver class
>   \Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsMenuLink.
>
> Finally, you can use the plugin manager directly to add, update, and
>   remove definitions.

You could probably use [hook_menu_links_discovered_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter/8.2.x)  for your scenario.

---

Edit: You want to edit the permission to access that link, so it automatically does not show up in the menu.

Read on drupal.org: /node/2311427

> Drupal 8
>
> In Drupal 8, you can support dynamic permissions by referencing a
>   function that will dynamically define those permissions. This callback
>   defines the permissions for core's filter module.
>
> ```
> // in filter.permissions.yml
>
>
> permission_callbacks:
>   - Drupal\filter\FilterPermissions::permissions
>
> // in FilterPermissions.php
>
> class FilterPermissions {
>   public function permissions() {
>     $permissions = [];
>     // Generate permissions for each text format. Warn the administrator that any
>     // of them are potentially unsafe.
>     /** @var \Drupal\filter\FilterFormatInterface[] $formats */
>     $formats = $this->entityManager->getStorage('filter_format')->loadByProperties(['status' => TRUE]);
>     uasort($formats, 'Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase::sort');
>     foreach ($formats as $format) {
>       if ($permission = $format->getPermissionName()) {
>         $permissions[$permission] = [
>           'title' => $this->t('Use the @label text format', ['@url' => $format->url(), '@label' => $format->label()]),
>           'description' => String::placeholder($this->t('Warning: This permission may have security implications depending on how the text format is configured.')),
>         ];
>       }
>     }
>     return $permissions;
>   }
> }
> ```

You should also read this article https://www.lullabot.com/articles/what-happened-to-hook_menu-in-drupal-8 (scroll down to "Access Control" and "Hook_Menu_Alter").

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this hook_menu_links_discovered_alter, but this is not useful to hide menu.
Kindly check that this hook is only useful for **The link definitions to be altered.**

Comment: Referring to above article, I tried that but that will give only access denied, it wont hide menu.