# Alter content translation page access based on content's field value

Tags: 8, users, i18n-l10n, nodes

I have a content type: `Test`
I want to alter the permission to translate it based on one of it's field value.
Take the following use-case (field type, and role doesn't matter):

If `field_test == '1'` then the `Translate` link task should not be displayed (because the current user role does not have permission to view it).

What do you suggest?

Comment: Hi, what type of field is fielt_test ?
Taxonomy term reference, boolean checkbox or select list or simply text field?

Comment: Furthermore, what roles do you have in your website ?
Could you please post all of this to the quesiton description ?

Comment: Field type and role doesn't matter in this question. I just want to find the right place where I can put my own business logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this official link helped:

**About route alteration:**
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

**About access check:**
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes

@Oleg Videnov:
The first link you provided in your answer is good as well!

Comment: I have tried same methods but this does not work. I have posted my issue here. Can you please post Answer how you solved this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296392/altering-existing-route-for-translation-overview-page-ie-entity-node-content-tr. @ssibal

Answer (score 3):

I think something like that already has been answered before:

Could you take a look and tell us if that helps you ?

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/208817/8375

Other outside resources: https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/controlling-access-drupal-8-routes-access-checks

Comment: The first link is a good help (however I didn't used that).
The second one is outdated! I think that should be removed!

Comment: would you mind posting the code that helped you, because i am also looking for  solution

Comment: It just posted it after yours!