# How to create a permission with logic

Tags: 8, users

I need to create a permission to allow users to see the content overview page (/admin/content) only during business hours (9 AM to 5 PM).

Drupal core comes with the "Access the Content overview page" permission; but I need "Access the Content overview page during work hours".

I know how to create a permission and how to test that the user has the permission. What I don't understand is how to assign some logic to a permission itself (for example, *within business hours*).

I can do this in mymodule.permissions.yml.

```
access content overview within business hours:
  title: 'Access the Content overview page within business hours'
  restrict access: TRUE
```

I can check the user has the permission with `\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access content overview within business hours')`.

How can I make the permission return `TRUE` only during business hours?
How can I check the permission only when the users visits the content overview page?

I can foresee multiple use cases for needing some logic implementation within the permission itself, for example when allowing/restricting access to certain pages depending on whether the environment is development or production, or allowing/restricting access depending on the value of some fields.

**- EDIT -**

As suggested in the comments, I've started by creating the following three files on my module; but it doesn't work. The `CustomAccessChecks::access` never gets called.

File: custom_access.services.yml

```
services:
  custom_access.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\custom_access\Routing\AdminRouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
  custom_access.access_checker:
    class: Drupal\custom_access\Access\CustomAccessChecks
    tags:
      - { name: access_check }
```

File: src/Access/CustomAccessChecks.php

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_access\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\Access\AccessInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultAllowed;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

class CustomAccessChecks implements AccessInterface {

  /**
   * A custom access check.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for this account.
   */
  public function access(Route $route, RouteMatchInterface $route_match, AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResultAllowed::allowedIf((int) $account->id() === 1);
  }
}
```

File: AdminRouteSubscriber.php

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_access\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class AdminRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

    if ($route = $collection->get('system.admin_content')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_custom_access', '\Drupal\custom_access\Access\CustomAccessChecks::access');
    }
  }
}
```

As expected, visiting '/admin/content' as the main administrator `$account->id() === 1` works, but when visiting as another authenticated user, I still can access the page.

What I'm missing?

Comment: I believe the most voted answer in this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204582/alter-the-access-of-menu-link-before-rendering outlines what you need to do.

Comment: That’s probably a good solution.

Comment: @GiorgosK and Kevin Thank you so much for the suggestion. I've updated my question above to include some code that I've added to my "custom_access" module. This code is mostly copied from the other answer as a prof of concept. Still not including the logic for the time of the day, though.

Answer (score 1):

When the access to a route doesn't depend uniquely on a single permission, you need to implement what [Access checking on routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes) describes.

- Implement a service tagged *access_check*
- Associate it with the route

Since you are altering the route defined from another module, you need to also follow [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones).

#### example.services.yml

```
services:
  example.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\example\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }

  example.access_checker:
    class: Drupal\example\Access\CustomAccessCheck
    tags:
      - { name: access_check }
```

#### RouteSubscriber.php

```
namespace Drupal\example\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('system.admin_content')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_custom_access', 'example.access_checker::access');
    }
  }
```

#### CustomAccessCheck.php

```
namespace Drupal\example\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\Access\AccessInterface;

/**
 * Checks access for displaying configuration translation page.
 */
class CustomAccessCheck implements AccessInterface {

  /**
   * A custom access check.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for this account.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface
   *   The access result.
   */
  public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
    // Check permissions and combine that with any custom access checking needed. Pass forward
    // parameters from the route and/or request as needed.
    return ($account->hasPermission('access content overview within business hours') && $this->checkTimeAccess()) ? AccessResult::allowed() : AccessResult::forbidden();
  }

}
```

The `checkTimeAccess()` method I didn't write should check if the user is trying to access the route during the business hours.

I cannot tell what happens with a route using the *_permission* requirement when it is altered to use also the *_custom_access* requirement. I didn't find the Drupal core code handling the access to a route, so I cannot say which requirement is used first.
I didn't also find a way to remove requirements from a route when altering it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code but it didn't work.

Comment: Using kint($route) I can see that there is a requirement `'_permission' => string(27) "access administration pages"`. It may be possible that Drupal is going with that requirement, which comes first. It is interesting that on D8 this particular route is overriden by a views, and I can see in the views administration that the path that is set is "/admin/content/node", however; this page really uses "/admin/content". I wonder whether this doesn't work because the views, or because of the requirement.

Comment: /admin/content/node is the default tab shown on /admin/content; it's not /admin/content/node that overrides /admin/content. As far as I recall, the permission to see /admin/content/node is inherited from /admin/content, so a user who doesn't have the permission to visit /admin/content cannot visit /admin/content/node either.